# What buildozer spec requirements do I need to include?

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, buildozer

I need your help.

I'm trying to create a small app that plays videos. I have it running on my Windows PC, it works fine. The problem is that I can't seem to deploy it to my phone.

To clarify:

- The code compiles fine and with no issues.
- The apk is created without issues.
- As soon as the apk is deployed and installed, the app opens the splash screen and crashes.

I have been trying every kind of requirement combinations. Here are the modules I am using:

```
import threading
import sys
from kivy.uix.video import Video
import pyaudio
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from functools import partial
from cv2 import cv2
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivvy.utils import platform
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os
```

I have used:

```
requirements = python3, kivy, canvas, kivymd, opencv-python, pillow, frame, gradlepay
```

Are there any other requirements I need to add?

Thank you for your time.

I have tried various combinations of requirements. I've thrown everything and the kitchen sink into that one line, and to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I came along this problem myself and the problem with these requirements is often that the modules you import require other modules themselves and often you have to also include these in the requirements. 
I solved this problem by putting every import statement in a try-except statement and print out the error so I could see what went wrong or which requirement is missing - like so:

```py
try:
    import some_module
except BaseException as e:
    open("/sdcard/error_log.txt", "w").write(e)  # Creates a file and writes the error to it
```